# Compare vector<int> with no name

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::list<int> list{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> vec1{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> vec2{ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    if(vector<int>(list.begin(), list.end()) == vec1)
    {
        cout << "haha";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There is no name in `vector<int>(list.begin(), list.end())`.
How is it possible to compare `vector<int>` with no name and `vec1`.

Comment: You don't compare the "names", you compare *objects*. And `vector<int>(list.begin(), list.end())` will create a (temporary) object that can be compared to any other compatible object.

Comment: It's a temporary, which exists while evaluating the statement. This is just fine, and your program should output "haha".

Comment: Related: `std::equal` can do the same thing without the intermediate container construction, once you know the sequences sizes are the same. E.g. `if(list.size() == vec1.size() && std::equal(list.begin(), list.end(), vec1.begin()))` . Ranges in C++20 can go even further.

Comment: Are you surprised by the behaviour of `int i = 1; if (i == 1) { cout << "haha"; }`? `1` has no name either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is it possible to compare vector with no name and vec1.

`std::vector` has overloaded [`operator==`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) as a non-member function.

```
template< class T, class Alloc >

bool operator==( const std::vector<T,Alloc>& lhs,
                 const std::vector<T,Alloc>& rhs );
```

This means that when you wrote:

```
vector<int>(list.begin(), list.end()) == vec1
```

a **temporary `std::vector<int>` object** is created and is passed as the first argument to the above shown overloaded `operator==` while `vec1` is passed as the second argument to the same overloaded `operator==` and thus the comparison succeeds. In other words, the first parameter `lhs` is bound to the temporary `std::vector<int>` while the second parameter `rhs` is bound to `vec1`.